# Cálculo utilizando Angular JS

Tags: jquery, angularjs

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]Consegui com ajuda do Esmigol resolver um dos problemas e estou insistindo aqui pois nao encontrei nada na internet que possa me ajudar. Tem poucos exemplos do que preciso na internet. O calculo da linha está ok (quantidade x valor unitario) mais a soma e subtração do Valor Total que estou apanhando. O que estou fazendo de errado
[![

```js
$scope.valorClaro = [
        {id: 1, gb: 0, qtd: '', preco: 39.99, descricao: "Ligações Ilimitadas", operadora: "Tim"},
        {
            id: 2,
            gb: 0.5,
            qtd: '',
            preco: 45.99,
            descricao: "Ligações Ilimitadas + WhatsApp + SMS + Conteúdo Digital",
            operadora: "Claro"
        }
    ]

    $scope.soma = 0;

    $scope.multiplicaValor = function (index) {
        index.totalLinha = index.qtd * index.preco;
        angular.forEach($scope.valorClaro, function () {
            $scope.soma += index.qtd * index.preco;
        });
        console.log(index.totalLinha);
    }
```

```html
<form name="formSimula">
    <div class="card mt-3">
        <div class="card-header font-weight-bold">
            <img src="./dist/images/icon-claro.png"> Simulador Planos Claro
            <span class="float-right" style="font-size: 30px;">{{soma | currency}}</span>
        </div>

        <table class="table table-hover mb-0" style="font-size: 0.875em;">
            <thead>
            <tr class="alert-warning d-flex">
                <th class="text-center col-1">GB</th>
                <th class="col-2">Valor</th>
                <th class="col-5">Descrição</th>
                <th class="col-2 text-center">Qtd Linhas</th>
                <th class="col-2">Total</th>
            </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
            <tr class="d-flex font-weight-bold font-open" ng-repeat="claro in valorClaro">
                <td class="align-middle text-center col-1">{{claro.gb}}</td>
                <td class="col-2 align-middle">{{ claro.preco | currency}}</td>
                <td class="align-middle col-5">{{ claro.descricao}}</td>
                <td class="align-middle col-2 text-center">
                    <input type="text" class="form-control form-control-sm text-center" ng-model="claro.qtd"
                           ng-change="multiplicaValor(claro)">
                </td>
                <td class="align-middle col-2">
                    <input type="text" class="form-control form-control-sm text-center"
                           value="{{claro.totalLinha | currency}}">
                </td>
            </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
</form>
```

][2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/t85cY.jpg)][2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/t85cY.jpg)

Comment: Pode nos prover sua marcação HTML também? Pelo menos deste bloco que é exibido na imagem...

Comment: @Dinei inclui o código HTML

Comment: O seu `ng-model` no `input` tem que fazer referência ao objeto `claro`: `ng-model="claro.preco"`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Você não precisa colocar um id no input para pegar o valor digitado, adicione no seu array mais uma variável no caso abaixo criei com o nome de quantidade, ai no input coloque como ng-model essa variável e em sua função de multiplicar passe o index do registro ai você terá acesso aos dados na função e poderá realizar a multiplicação da linha que quiser.

```js
angular.module('App').controller("AppCtrl", function($scope, $http) {
  $scope.valorClaro = [{
      id: 1,
      gb: 0,
      quantidade: 0,
      preco: 39.99,
      descricao: "Ligações Ilimitadas",
      operadora: "Claro",
totalLinha: 0
    },
    {
      id: 2,
      gb: 0.5,
      quantidade: 0,
      preco: 45.99,
      descricao: "Ligações Ilimitadas + WhatsApp + SMS + Conteúdo Digital",
      operadora: "Claro",
totalLinha: 0
    }
  ];

  $scope.totalLinha;
  $scope.multiplicaValor = function(index) {
    index.totalLinha = index.quantidade * index.preco;
  }
});
```

```html
<html>

<head>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.0/angular.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <table>
    <tbody>
      <tr class="d-flex font-weight-bold font-open" ng-repeat="claro in valorClaro">
        <td class="align-middle text-center col-1">{{claro.gb}}</td>
        <td class="col-2 align-middle">{{ claro.preco | currency}}</td>
        <td class="align-middle col-5">{{ claro.descricao}}</td>
        <td class="align-middle col-2 text-center">
          <input type="text" class="form-control form-control-sm text-center" id="linha" ng-model="claro.quantidade" ng-change="multiplicaValor(claro)">
        </td>
        <td class="align-middle col-2">
          <input type="text" class="form-control form-control-sm text-center" ng-model="claro.totalLinha">
        </td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>



</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Perfeito, somar o valor total seria isso? $scope.soma += index.totalLinha;

Comment: Isso... poderia fazer um loop, (for ou angular.Foreach) na sua lista $scope.valorClaro e então $scope.soma += indexDaLista.quantidade * indexDaLista.preco

Comment: Está correto isso?

Comment: A principio sim pois o loop irá percorrer todos os registros do array e irá fazer a quantidade vezes o preço e adicionar em uma variável($scope.soma) o que irá resultar no valor total.

Comment: Deu certo valeu a dica!